# Can't install Spring-XD properly on Windows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-xd

For using batch processing and some analysis, I'm trying to start some Spring-XD projects. I have worked with Spring-Boot previously. Sorry for my ignorance. I have followed official guide.

As a Windows user, instead of this `xd/bin>$ ./xd-singlenode` command, I put this : `E:\software\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\bin>xd-singlenode`. They are same right? I have defined all the path they have instructed to set.

But I'm getting this error :

> 1.3.1.RELEASE                    eXtreme Data
>
> Started : SingleNodeApplication Documentation:
> http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/
>
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
> Illegal reflective access by
> org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1
> (file:/E:/software/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE/xd/lib/groovy-all-2.4.4.jar)
> to method java.lang.Object.finalize() WARNING: Please consider
> reporting this to the maintainers of
> org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 WARNING: Use
> --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
> denied in a future release 2020-09-23T19:48:33+0600 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO
> main singlenode.SingleNodeApplication - Starting SingleNodeApplication
> v1.3.1.RELEASE on MUA with PID 12216
> (E:\software\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\lib\spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
> started by MUA in E:\software\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\bin)
> 2020-09-23T19:48:34+0600 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO main
> singlenode.SingleNodeApplication - Started SingleNodeApplication in
> 4.615 seconds (JVM running for 32.452) 2020-09-23T19:48:35+0600 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO main singlenode.SingleNodeApplication - Starting SingleNodeApplication v1.3.1.RELEASE on MUA with PID 12216
> (E:\software\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\lib\spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
> started by MUA in E:\software\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\bin)
> 2020-09-23T19:48:35+0600 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO main
> singlenode.SingleNodeApplication - Started SingleNodeApplication in
> 0.972 seconds (JVM running for 33.47) 2020-09-23T19:48:41+0600 1.3.1.RELEASE WARN main annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor':
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate
> Configuration. 2020-09-23T19:48:41+0600 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR main
> boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor':
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate
> Configuration.
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207)
> ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
> ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
> ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:83)
> ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.main(SingleNodeApplication.java:52)
> ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE] Caused by:
> javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate
> Configuration.
> at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:279)
> ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
> ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:381)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:174)
> ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
> ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> ... 16 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for
> length 1
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36)
> ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:119)
> ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:95)
> ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
> at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:31)
> ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
> at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
> ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:na]
> ... 21 common frames omitted Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor':
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate
> Configuration.
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
> at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:83)
> at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.main(SingleNodeApplication.java:52)
> Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate
> Configuration.
> at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:279)
> at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:381)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:174)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
> ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for
> length 1
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36)
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:119)
> at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:95)
> at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:31)
> at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
> ... 21 more
>
> E:\software\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\bin>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Spring XD is incompatible with your java version.
Are you using Java 11?

Spring XD was originally written for Java 7, and has been End-Of-Life since 2017.

New projects should use Spring Cloud Data Flow instead: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow

Comment: ok, thanks for suggesting this.. I don't know I YouTube suggested that to me, and took nearly 3 months from me.. and I read all those docs, nowhere it was written that it has faced it's end-of-life.. thanks for suggesting the new one...

Comment: It says so right on the front page: https://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/
"This project has been in EOL/EOS status since July 2017. Please review Spring Cloud Data Flow and the ecosystem-of-projects for further research, exploration, and use-case implementation."